# XML response gets blocked by CORS on angular 10

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest, angular-httpclient

I was working with an API which was giving me xml repsponse but unfortunately i'm not being able to retrieve the xml response. I get CORS issue on my browser through my angular app. But i can get the response from both the browser and also from postman.

I just need to get the xml response.

Here is my code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { xml2js } from 'xml2js';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  httpData;
  public xmlItems: any;

  ApiUser = '***';
  domain_name = 'website.com';
  ApiKey = '*****';
  Command = '****';
  ClientIp = '*********';
  ngOnInit() {
    this.http
      .get(
        `https://api.namecheap.com/xml.response?ApiUser=${this.ApiUser}&ApiKey=${this.ApiKey}&UserName=*****&ClientIp=${this.ClientIp}&Command=${this.Command}&DomainList=${this.domain_name}`,
        {
          headers: new HttpHeaders()
            .set('Content-Type', 'text/xml')
            .append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET')
            .append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            .append(
              'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
              'Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Request-Method'
            ),
          responseType: 'text',
        }
      )
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.parseXML(data).then((data) => {
          this.xmlItems = data;
        });
      });
  }

  parseXML(data) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      var k: string | number,
        arr = [],
        parser = new xml2js.Parser({
          trim: true,
          explicitArray: true,
        });
      parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
        var obj = result.ApiResponse;
        for (k in obj.CommandResponse) {
          var item = obj.CommandResponse[k];
          arr.push({
            info: item.DomainCheckResult[0],
          });
        }
        resolve(arr);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

My modules

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

html file

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of xmlItems">
  <li>{{ item.DomainCheckResult }}</li>
</ul>
```

So this is all the codes. I get `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.....` and also this error `(Reason: CORS request did not succeed)`
Could anyone help me why i'm not getting the response while i declared all the headers and gave appropiate credintials.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: CORS requires **ResponseHeaders** to be set by server.

Comment: Well, I am fetching an XML data from the server through an API I can't get enough access to the server. But there should be ways to bypass the cors right? 
I've added headers on my code so that the server could prevent the errors. 
now it's giving me `Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing`. Is my code right or it's up to the server? 
BTW I can get the response from **postman** and also if I paste the API link on the browser it also gives me output but through my app, it's giving me an error. 
what should I do?

Comment: postman is another origin. Please check the response from server in network console. Does it include the response header? If yes, what's the value? After all there are also browser addons which let you bypass those errors.

Comment: On the network it's blocking